# Implementing Multiple PickerView inside TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I  trying to implement Multiple `UIPickerView` inside `UITableView`, each row will contain an independent `UIPickerView`. The problem is when I change value in one `PickerView`, it automatically changes in on other row as well, but sometimes not.

But I want is to have independent `UIPickerView` for each `UITableViewCell`.

[image] [image]

[image]

Custom Cell

```
    class PrayerCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var detailView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var toggleAlarm: UISwitch!

    var isObserving = false;


    class var expandedHeight: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 200
        }
    }

    class var defaultHeight: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 44
        }
    }

    func checkHeight() {
        detailView.hidden = (frame.size.height < PrayerCell.expandedHeight)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(false, animated: false)
    }

    func watchFrameChanges() {
        if !isObserving {
            addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [.New, .Initial], context: nil)
            isObserving = true;
        }
    }

    func ignoreFrameChanges() {
        if isObserving {
            removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
            isObserving = false;
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "frame" {
            checkHeight()
        }
    }

    let pickerData = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(pickerData[row])
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(row)
        updateLabel()
    }

    func updateLabel(){
        // let value = pickerData[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        // minsBeforeLabel.text = String(value) + " Minutes Before "
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the prepareForReuse method in UITableViewCell to reset the UIPickerView

Comment: @Chaitanya Sorry I forgot to mention that I need undependent UIPickerView for each UITableViewCell. But I am unable to do so.

Comment: When you make a custom tableviewcell, your cells get reused. That's the reason why you are getting this behaviour. To get undependent UIPickerView for each UITableViewCell, you need to use override func prepareForReuse() to reset or reinitialize UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following open source implementation of what you want.

[Bohr](https://github.com/Dromaguirre/Bohr)